# Date format on Windows 10 and ApplicationPoolIdentity

Tags: c#, iis, windows-10, regional-settings, applicationpoolidentity

For some reason Windows 10 changed date format for Polish language (both short and long). Currently, when I call `DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("d")` in C# it returns `06.09.2015` while on Windows 8.1 it returns `2015-09-06`.

I changed both short and long date formats in Regional Settings and also copied these settings to system accounts and newly created accounts. It works for Windows but things get more interesting when I try to run it in web application (ASP.NET MVC).
When the application pool is set to run as LocalSystem it works. However, when it runs as ApplicationPoolIdentity (the default value) it still returns the default date format.

Given that, I have two questions:

1. Why did Microsoft change the date format for Polish (link to Technet or similar site highly appreciated)?
2. How to set my custom date format for application pools running as ApplicationPoolIdentity?